# Receive unicast UDP packet in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, networking

I want to write a Silverlight application that would be receiving UDP packets on a given port, e.g. 5004. Essentially I want:

```
byte[] data = new UdpClient(5004).Receive(ref endPoint);
```

What would be an equivalent of that code in Silverlight?

Comment: Can't be done. In SL6, maybe.

Comment: It can't be done for unicast. You can do it for multicast in the local network - depending on your problem that might be helpful. You can also *send* unicast udp packets to targets outside the local network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sockets are available as of Silverlight 2, though it doesn't include the UdpClient.

System.Net.Sockets

http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2008/03/07/silverlight-2-and-sockets.aspx